# Django form with conditions for multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to Django, and I've been fighting with this form for over a week now. I started this first because it is the core of my project. What I ultimately want is a single form that has a condition that the user can set, to add data to a second form when they check a radio box (will do that in jquery). I want to give admins the ability to register users, but I have a special subclass of users called operators that need additional information in a separate model. I almost have it working right now, but all users get added to the special subclass. Please help!

**EDIT:** What's not working is that I want to have the Admins register a user on a single form that can create users and if they check a button, then fill out the rest of the form for operators. I have the second part working (they can create an operator), but I also want them be able to create a regular user with the same form (that doesn't use the operator model). Can this be done?

Here is my code. *NOTE*: I messed up the password registration in this code, but I'll fix that later. Just working on this core functionality right now.

**Models**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class OperatorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cdl = models.ManyToManyField('CDL', blank=True)
    endorsement = models.ManyToManyField('Endorsement', blank=True)
    cdl_expiration = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**Views**

```
class OperatorCreateView(CreateView):
    model = OperatorProfile
    template_name = 'pages/operatorprofile_form.html'
    form_class = UserCreationMultiForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Save the user first, because the profile needs a user before it
        # can be saved.

        user = form['user'].save()
        user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='Operators'))
        profile = form['profile'].save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        form['profile'].save_m2m()

        return redirect(reverse_lazy('index'))
```

**Forms**

```
# Operator Creation Form
class OperatorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OperatorProfile
        exclude = ['user']


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password_confirm = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if not password_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")
        if password != password_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords do not match")
        return password_confirm

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'bio']


class UserCreationMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user': UserProfileForm,
        'profile': OperatorProfileForm,
    }
```

Comment: You haven't said what's not working, or what you are having problems with.

Comment: Added an edit to explain the issue more

Comment: If you unltimately want to use jquery, why not submit the second form in every submission but define a set of defaults in case there is nothing there. You can hide/show the fields using the radio button you described.

Comment: Main issue with that is that the users show up in my Operator model. That is what I'm using to distinguish between special users and non special users. Looks like I just need to rework my thought process on this one.